# User VerificationCodes generate method always returns "Invalid Input" error

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to generate backup verification codes via the API, and it always returns a generic "Invalid input" 403 error.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/verificationCodes/generate

This occurs even when using the API explorer as a super admin. I'm supplying my email address in the `userKey`, and am authenticating using Oauth2 w/ the same email. This is the response I'm getting:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Input"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Input"
 }
}
```

What is causing this error?

It might be worth noting that the `list` method works without error. The `generate` and `invalidate` methods both return a `400` error.

Comment: Have you implemented the [guides and prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites) using Directory API?

Comment: Yes, all the basics are in place. Most other user-based API calls work fine, it's just this one that seems to be giving me issues.